# Java excluding images when building jar file

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, packaging

I made a project with a GUI in Netbeans. The GUI has a label called *GIFL2* which loads an image when a button is pressed, via

```
GIFL2.setText("");
GIFL2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src/torrehanoirecursion/" + path));
```

This works just fine in Netbeans when I run the code inside. **It does load the image successfully**.

Problem is, when I build the project and I open the jar file, the images don't load.
I initially thought it was because the images were inside an img folder, which was in turn inside of src. So the relative path for the folder was **src/torrehanoirecursion/img**

However, I moved all of the images to src itself, with no folder, because I read that java could be excluding them for not being part of src, but it still doesn't work. No errors or anything, it simply doesn't load them into the jar.

I went to project > properties > packaging. "Copy dependent libraries" is checked, 
"build jar on compile" is checked, "compress jar" is unchecked, and "exclude from jar" is completely empty.

**Any ideas as to what might be happening?**

Comment: You cannot use a File to load something stored in a jar. It must be a file on disk.

Comment: So whats a workaround for this? That doesn't involve maven

Comment: Depends on whether you want your image to be a resource on the classpath or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you use **Maven** you should put all resources you want to include on target jar under `src/main/resources` directory on your project:

```
pom.xml
src/main/java
src/main/java/resources
src/main/java/resources/img1
```

You can also include files under different directories as for example `src/other-resources`. This case on your pom.xml you should set these paths under **build** section as follow:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/other-resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

For more details see at **Maven resources plugin** documentation: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html

---

**Update: Solution with not Maven project via Netbeans**

As you specified you're project is not managed with Maven I reported steps that could allow you to solve with Netbeans.

1. Create a `resources` directory on root path of your project
2. Open your project properties on Netbeans IDE and select `Sources`on categories section
3. Add the `resources` folder on **Source package folder** section

Then target jar should contain all files under `resources` directory on classpath.

---

**Update: Manually inject resources on target jar**

At the end you can also inject the whole `src/main/java/resources` directory on your target jar **manually** with the following command **after the build** ( you should automate this at least with a bash script or specific task on Netbeans ):

```
cd src/main/java/
jar uf project.jar resources
```

Comment: This isn't a maven project though...I'm not allowed to use maven

Comment: You are not allowed to use Maven?? Sounds like there is a bit of context missing for the question here.

Comment: Also it should not be necessary to explicitly set the src/main/resources directory as a resource directory to Maven as this is the default.

Comment: You're right @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen. I've updated my question specifying this concept

Comment: It's an uni project and we haven't yet seen Maven.

And thank you for the tip, but it's still not working, it doesn't load anything when I open the jar, but it does when I run it from the IDE

Comment: I've included a manual solution that anycase should allow you to go on with this ( as it is not possible for me to help you without knowing complete IDE settings ). I hope this help for your uni project